# What's with the [] in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Two code samples:

First:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.equation = {};
    $scope.change = function() {
        $scope.equation.output = Number($scope.equation.x) + 2;
    }
});
```

Second:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.equation = {};
    $scope.change = function() {
        $scope.equation.output = Number($scope.equation.x) + 2;
    }
}]);
```

I currently have both of them working.

What's with the `[]` enclosing the callback in the second sample? And what is different between these implementations?

Comment: it's a way to avoid problems with minifications. [read this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/13/angularjs-controllers-dependencies-and-minification.aspx)

Comment: @gdoron, so it's a good practice do go and code like the second example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Purpose of Square Bracket use in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032068/purpose-of-square-bracket-use-in-angular)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because angular uses dependency injection, it read the parameter names for methods & uses reflection to inject the service that you want to inject

what happens with minification is that it basically renames the parameter names & shorten them, so your first example without `[]` wont work, why?

because using the array to specify the parameter names, will match the array param to the function params

**Example**

```
// 1- using the array notation
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function(z) {} ]);
// 'z' this will be '$scope' the actual name will be taken from the array not the parameter name

// 2- using the normal notation (this is similiar to what will be producted by the minifier if you didn't use the array notation
app.controller('MyCtrl', function(z /* what is this ? */ ) {} );
// the code will fail because angular doesn't understand what 'z' means and has no way to map to anything else
```

check [this article](http://thegreenpizza.github.io/2013/05/25/building-minification-safe-angular.js-applications) for more details

---

**What should you use ?**

so you can use the `[]` example to make your code works with minification **or** you use a node package called [ngmin](https://github.com/btford/ngmin), it basically refactors your code and transform it to use `[]` notation *(note: it fails in a couple of extreme cases)* but works generally