# Angular $timeout in coffeescript class

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I have an Angular service written as a coffeescript class. The basics work fine, but I'm struggling to add a $timeout function (which should call the close method):

```
class AlertService
  constructor: ($timeout) ->
    @timeout = $timeout
    @alerts = []

  getAlerts: -> @alerts

  addAlert: (type, msg) ->
    alert = {type: type, msg:msg}
    @alerts.push alert
    @timeout ****Can't work out what goes here ******

  closeAlert: (alert) ->
    @alerts = @alerts.filter (x) -> x isnt alert

AlertService.$inject = ['$timeout']
app.factory 'alertService', -> new AlertService
```

Everything I've tried simply results in an 'undefined is not a function' error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think newing up is causing the issue. let angular provide you the instance. `app.factory 'alertService', -> AlertService` try chaingin it to `app.factory 'alertService', AlertService`

Comment: Could be on to something there, but it now gives 'Provider 'alertService' must return a value from $get factory method.'

Comment: I am not sure about coffeescript. But i guess you could really just use service instead of factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what you need is a service not a factory.

Try:-

```
class AlertService

  @$inject = ['$timeout']

  constructor: ($timeout) ->
    @timeout = $timeout
    @alerts = []

  getAlerts: -> @alerts

  addAlert: (type, msg) ->
    alert = {type: type, msg:msg}
    @alerts.push alert
    @timeout (=> @closeAlert(alert)), 2000


  closeAlert: (alert) ->
    @alerts = @alerts.filter (x) -> x isnt alert

app.service 'alertService', AlertService
```

Comment: that's what @garbanzio seems to be saying below too

Comment: @Owen I just used this to convert to js and ran and it works. Try the snippet in my example. You should not new up stuffs, it will cause anything injected using angular DI to be ignored when you new up.

Comment: What is the `@timeout ****Can't work out what goes here ******` code you have? I am not a coffee expert but using converter to generate script.

Comment: at the moment, I'm using @garbanzio's suggestion below: (=> @closeAlert(alert)), 2000

Comment: What is the issue? Doesn't it work after converting to service?

Comment: @Owen i.e because you have a typo `@$timeout (=> @closeAlert(alert)), 2000` should be `@timeout (=> @closeAlert(alert)), 2000`

Comment: Ok.. U changed your code again.. :) You can use alternate syntax `@$inject = ['$timeout']` as well which is more readable. I have pasted a shorted and concise code.. Btw time to switch to typescript? :)

Comment: Yep, I like the look of that!!

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this:

```
app.service 'AlertService', ['$timeout', class AlertService
  constructor: (@$timeout) ->
    @alerts = []

  getAlerts: -> @alerts

  addAlert: (type, msg) ->
    alert = {type: type, msg:msg}
    @alerts.push alert
    #this could probably be written a little better, but should work
    @$timeout ((alert) -> @closeAlert(alert)).bind(@, alert), 2000

  closeAlert: (alert) ->
    @alerts = @alerts.filter (x) -> x isnt alert

]
```

The fat arrow (=> as opposed to ->) will bind your `this` instance into the clojure. The callback for the timeout function is inside the parens, and the second parameter (timeout length) is `2000`.

When in doubt, I always check my coffeescript using a coffeescript->js compiler.

Comment: that's still giving the 'undefined is not a function' error

Comment: I think `AlertService.$inject = ['$timeout']` doesn't exactly compile as expected. Per this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032068/purpose-of-square-bracket-use-in-angular#answer-18033952 , Angular + Coffeescript requires the use of the bracket syntax for dependency injection. Use the bracket syntax, as mentioned [here](http://benhollis.net/blog/2014/01/17/cleanly-declaring-angularjs-services-with-coffeescript/). Or just switch to plain js.

Comment: @Owen let me know if that worked and I will update the answer. :)

Comment: the bracket syntax makes no difference, I'm afraid

Comment: try the edited example verbatim. make sure you console.log @$timeout right before it is called, or step in to the compiled js.

Comment: @Owen this is why coffeescript is a pain in the ass and I try to stay away from it.

Comment: Now gives 'Unknown provider: alertServiceProvider <- alertService'

Comment: but that was just because of AlertService instead of alertService

Comment: that's now running with no error, but not closing the alert after the timeout. I suspect that '@$timeout (=> @closeAlert(alert)), 2000' isn't passing the alert through to the close method

Comment: OK the issue is that you need to bind the local variable `alert` to the clojure. I don't exactly know the most elegant way to do this in coffeescript, but this should work. Change `@$timeout (=> @closeAlert()), 2000` to `@$timeout ((alert) -> @closeAlert(alert)).bind(@, alert), 2000` . Also, maybe mark mine as correct since it is the one you are using? Up to you ;)