# When to specify angularjs dependency modules?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-module

I've seen some instances where you can immediately use angular services in providers, e.g.:

```
.module('yea.buddy', [
    'ui-translate'
])
.config(function($translateProvider) { ... })
```

versus

```
.module('yea.buddy.two', [
    'some-module'
])
.config(['some-module-service', function(someModuleService) { ... }])
```

What's the difference between the two? When is the resource implied, and square brace notation not needed?

edit: I have an instance where there is some confusion, and I'm asking because I don't want to break minification.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Purpose of Square Bracket use in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032068/purpose-of-square-bracket-use-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

1. In the module e.g angular.module('app',[]); square brace is for the dependancy modules. This is mandatory if you have any dependancy you must include here either you are going to minify or not.
2. For creating any controller, services, directive and filter you must provide your respective dependancy if you want to minify. If you don't want to minify it is optional
3. In case of angular.module('app',[]).config(), it is same as item 2 that means it is optional if you are not going to minify

**Bonus:**

Why do Angular need?

Let try to understand how angular detect dependancy from the function arguments. The ordering of the arguments is useless. If you can change ordering of any argument, it will work without any issue. Actually angular maintain a global array $injector where it store every single instance where array index (Object Properties) is the your provided name while creating a service or filter or any other components.  For example you created an service

```
  angular.module('app',[]).service('good', function(){

  });
```

So angular have

```
$injector['good'] = service/filter etc output
```

Okay let back to the main topic. So when you can try to inject your newly created service 'good' in a controller as an argument, angular first find out all provided arguments and restore its instance from the $injector[EACH_SINGLE_ARUGMENT] i.e for your case $injector['good']

But when you minify your code, most of the time it minify the function argument. For example, 'good' will be 'a' . As a result angular fails to detect. Thats why angular uses this tricks so when you provide your dependancy in a square brace as well e.g.

```
app.controller(['good', function(good) {
 }] );
```

angular takes the name from this array because minify script does not change the array values. Because minify script normally does following:

```
  app.controller(['good', function(a) {
   }] );
```

Hope it you will help you a bit.