# What is the difference between these two ways of injecting into a controller in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I've noticed that in documentation, it is standard to declare a controller with dependencies in Angular as follows ...

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtlr', ['$scope', function($scope){
    // controller functionality goes here
}]);
```

Yet, I've noticed that the following has exactly the same behavior ...

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtlr', function($scope){
    // controller functionality goes here
});
```

What is the difference between these two methods and what is the "correct" way if any?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032068/what-is-the-purpose-of-square-bracket-usage-in-angular

Comment: and there's  third way using `functionName.$inject =[/* dependencies*/]`

Comment: It is a best practice to use `['$scope']...` In order to avoid problems directly binded to minification.
When running a minification without directly injecting `$scope`, it will be switched with `e` in this way:

    `angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("MyCtrl",function(e){e.functionalities...`
and Angular will not know how to use `$scope` anymore.
Instead, when using `$scope` injection, it will be no longer switched with `e` and Angular will not be lost.