# Angularjs specification for scope and http

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am learning angular,here I am trying to fecth json data, but I am not able to understand what (`$scope`,`$http`) and (`scope`,`http`) means .Looking for your value able answer.

Here is code:

```
abc.controller('abcCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function (scope, http){

}]);
```

Comment: You might find your answer in the docs (dependency injection): https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the syntax of `angularJS` uses **[Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)**. The [$scope](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_scopes.asp)  and [$http](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp) are the features provided by angularJS. Now, to use them, you need to inject them into the `controller`.

In your above code, you are injecting `$scope` and `$http` in the controller. There are two ways to declare a controller

#### First way

```
abc.controller('abcCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function (scope, http){
   //use them as "scope" and "http"
}]);
```

#### Second Way

```
abc.controller('abcCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    //use them as "$scope" and "$http"
    // here "scope" and "http" wont be available
});
```

[You can understand the difference from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032068/what-is-the-purpose-of-square-bracket-usage-in-angular)(In short, its about minification which can now be ignored,thanks to `ng-annotate` package). So, coming back to your question, `scope` is just a **declaration** of `$scope` which is being used in **First way** of controller.

Comment: @SudhaKushwaha If you find it helpful, please mark it as an answer and upvote it too :)

Comment: Shashank what will happen if i delete scope ?

Comment: @SudhaKushwaha Delete as in ? Can you plz elaborate with sample code

Answer (score 0):

The scope is the binding part between the HTML (view) and the JavaScript (controller).The scope is an object with the available properties and methods.The scope is available for both the view and the controller.

For example:

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h1>Hello : {{name}}</h1>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "Sudha";
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and

$http is an AngularJS service for reading data from remote servers.

For reference go [$scope](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_scopes.asp) and [$http](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This is known as **dependency injection** in AngularJS, where **$Scope** is the binding part between the HTML (view) and the JavaScript (controller) and **$http** a *http* service provider. Basically what you're trying to do is inject these two into your controller based on a syntax.

Please go through the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di), [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), [scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) for more info.